# problema para recibir datos de la URl

Tags: php, url, get

tengo un problema a la hora de recibir un dato por la url.

Desde un QR me viene dada una URL con una variable .com/FormularioSalud/index.php?medico=rocio

que despues recogo el dato y lo dibujo en un correo que se envia al cliente

$name = $_GET['medico'];

'

### Nuevo formulario desde'. $name .'

Pero cuando el cliente recibe el correo no aparece dibujado el nombre (variable)

Comment: Necesitamos ver el codigo. Como sustituyes el nombre del medico en la plantilla  de correo

Comment: lo sustituyo de esta manera /* MENSAJE  */
$mensajeAdmin = '<h2>Nuevo formulario desde'. $name .' </h2>

Comment: No hay forma de ayudarte mientras no se vea el código bro